# The syntax of this MySQL logic?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I have 5 joined tables as follows:

```
SELECT `t1`.`name` as 't1 name', 
`t2`.`name` as 't2 name',
`t3`.`name` as 't3 name',
`t4`.`name` as 't4 name',
`t5`.`name` as 't5 name'

FROM `myscheme`.`t1` 
JOIN `myscheme`.`t2`
ON `t1`.`code`= `t2`.`code`

JOIN `myscheme`.`t3`
ON `t2`.`code`= `t3`.`code`

JOIN `myscheme`.`t4`
ON `t3`.`code`= `t4`.`code`

JOIN `myscheme`.`t5`
ON `t4`.`code`= `t5`.`code`;
```

I want my WHERE clause to find the cases where not all `version` fields in the 5 tables starts with '55' but some do.

Here is a toy example. I am sorry that it is very difficult to post the exact tables and data due to complexity. This sample convey the meaning and the case:

t1:

```
------------------------
name    code    verison
------------------------
aa       11      55x
bb       22      33x
cc       99      55x
```

t2:

```
------------------------
name    code    verison
------------------------
dd       11      55x
ee       22      33x    
ff       99      55x
```

t3:

```
------------------------
name    code    verison
------------------------
gg       11      66x
hh       22      44x
ii       99      55x
```

t5:

```
------------------------
name    code    verison
------------------------
jj       11      66x
kk       22      88x
ll       99      55x
```

t5:

```
name    code    verison
------------------------
mm       11     66x
nn       22     88x
oo       99     55x
```

In these 5 table, there are two rows in each table that shares the same `code` among the 5 tables. I am interested in finding the rows that have the `version` starts with `55` in some tables (i.e. satisfied by OR statement), but not all tables (i.e. satisfied by NOT AND). In my toy example, this condition is satisfied by rows with `name`: `(aa, dd, gg, jj, mm)` (which all have the `code` `11`). But the other rows should not come out of the query. Why? because either none of their `version` start with `55`, (`name`: `bb`, `ee`, `hh`, `kk`, `mm`), or because all of them have `version` starts with `55` (`name`: `cc`, `ff`, `ii`, `ll`, `oo`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query 5 tables to check when they differ in one field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55707810/query-5-tables-to-check-when-they-differ-in-one-field)

Comment: Can you please show some sample data with expected results? I'm finding your criteria a little hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
where t1.version like '55%' or
      t2.version like '55%' or
      t3.version like '55%' or
      t4.version like '55%' or
      t5.version like '55%'
```

EDIT:

For your clarification, you can add:

```
where (t1.version like '55%' or
       t2.version like '55%' or
       t3.version like '55%' or
       t4.version like '55%' or
       t5.version like '55%' 
      ) and
      (least(t1.version, t2.version, t3.version, t4.version, t5.version) not like '55%' or
       greatest(t1.version, t2.version, t3.version, t4.version, t5.version) not like '55%'
      )
```

Comment: This will be true also if all the 5 versions begins with 55 but OP wants some and not all at the same time

Answer (score 0):

```
where (t1.version like '55%' or -- at least one version starts with 55
      t2.version like '55%' or
      t3.version like '55%' or
      t4.version like '55%' or
      t5.version like '55%')
and not (t1.version like '55%' and -- all versions start with 55, so we negate with NOT
      t2.version like '55%' and
      t3.version like '55%' and
      t4.version like '55%' and
      t5.version like '55%')
```

The first clause means that at least one of the version fields starts with 55.

The second clause (which is negated with NOT) would only be true if the all started with 55.

Answer (score 0):

If your table isn't too big, you could also try something like this:

```
WHERE
    CONCAT_WS(LEFT(t1.version, 2),
            LEFT(t2.version, 2),
            LEFT(t3.version, 2),
            LEFT(t4.version, 2),
            LEFT(t5.version, 2)) IN ('55' , '5555', '555555', '55555555');
```